# php is not working in broswer after installing, but when php -i is working

Tags: php, linux, httpd.conf

i have installed php, it is working in terminal when entered 
*php -i*

but in browser its not working, when i entered 
localhost/info.php.

Checked the httpd.conf, every thing seems to be correct.
I have compiled manually For installation,

Comment: Are sure your Apache is running?

Answer (score 1):

php -i worked means that your php-cli installed,but it's not corresponding  your apache or nginx,please check the httpd.conf if the follow mode is open :

```
LoadModule php5_module 'Directory'
```